# What does the "simd" prefix mean in SceneKit?

Tags: ios, scenekit, arkit

There is a `SCNNode` category named `SCNNode(SIMD)`, which declares some properties like `simdPosition`, `simdRotation` and so on. It seems these are duplicated properties of the original/normal properties `position` and `rotation`.

```
@property(nonatomic) simd_float3 simdPosition API_AVAILABLE(macos(10.13), ios(11.0), tvos(11.0), watchos(4.0));
@property(nonatomic) simd_float4 simdRotation API_AVAILABLE(macos(10.13), ios(11.0), tvos(11.0), watchos(4.0));
```

What's the difference between `position` and `simdPosition`? What does the prefix "simd" mean exactly?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SIMD

Comment: I've been wondering the same: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44732476/arkit-vs-scenekit-coordinates

Comment: Not exactly a duplicate, but see also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45182794/957768).

Answer (score 65, accepted):

### SIMD: Single Instruction Multiple Data

SIMD instructions allow you to perform the same operation on multiple values at the **same time**.

Let's see an example

### Serial Approach (NO SIMD)

We have these 4 Int32 values

```
let x0: Int32 = 10
let y0: Int32 = 20

let x1: Int32 = 30
let y1: Int32 = 40
```

Now we want to sum the 2 `x` and the 2 `y` values, so we write

```
let sumX = x0 + x1 // 40
let sumY = y0 + y1 // 60
```

In order to perform the 2 previous `sums` the CPU needs to

> 1. load x0 and x1 in memory and add them
> 2. load y0 and y1 in memory and add them

So the result is obtained with 2 operations.

I created some graphics to better show you the idea

> Step 1

[image]

> Step 2

[image]

### SIMD

Let's see now how SIMD does work.
First of all we need the input values stored in the proper SIMD format so

```
let x = simd_int2(10, 20)
let y = simd_int2(30, 40)
```

As you can see the previous `x` and `y` are vectors. Infact both `x` and `y`  contain 2 components.

Now we can write

```
let sum = x + y
```

Let's see what the CPU does in order to perform the previous operations

> 1. load x and y in memory and add them

[image]

That's it!

Both components of `x` and both components of `y` are **processed at the same time**.

### Parallel Programming

We are **NOT** talking about concurrent programming, instead this is real **parallel programming**.

As you can imagine in certain operation the SIMD approach is way faster then the serial one.

### Scene Kit

Let's see now an example in SceneKit

We want to add `10` to the `x`, `y` and `z` components of all the direct descendants of the scene node.

Using the classic **serial approach** we can write

```
for node in scene.rootNode.childNodes {
    node.position.x += 10
    node.position.y += 10
    node.position.z += 10
}
```

> Here a total of `childNodes.count * 3` operations is executed.

Let's see now how we can convert the previous code in SIMD instructions

```
let delta = simd_float3(10)
for node in scene.rootNode.childNodes {
    node.simdPosition += delta
}
```

This code is much faster then the previous one. I am not sure whether 2x or 3x faster but, believe me, it's way better.

### Wrap up

If you need to perform several times the same operation on different value, just use the SIMD properties :)

Comment: Brilliant explanation! Thanks a lot.

Comment: This is mostly correct but doesn't quite get at the core of the question. It isn't just that types from the SIMD library offer convenient syntax for operations like vector addition (after all, in Swift at least it's easy to do the same by extending `SCNVector3`). That library is also built to provide fast implementations of such operations using CPU-specific vector instructions (on both ARM and x86). And it provides a shared "vocabulary" for vectors and matrices for use by multiple frameworks, including ARKit, GameplayKit, Model I/O, and the Metal shader language.

Comment: Hey @Luca, thank you so much for your detailed answers! I and my team stuck on an issue for days ah :/ I posted an interesting question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63662318/arkit-apply-filter-cifilter-to-a-specific-part-vertex-of-an-arfaceanchor Would love your suggestions!

Answer (score 10):

SIMD is a small library built on top of [vector types](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/LanguageExtensions.html#vectors-and-extended-vectors) that you can import from `<simd/simd.h>`. It allows for more expressive and more performant code.

For instance using SIMD you can write

```
simd_float3 result = a + 2.0 * b;
```

instead of

```
SCNVector3 result = SCNVector3Make(a.x + 2.0 * b.x, a.y + 2.0 * b.y, a.z + 2.0 * b.z);
```

In Objective-C you can not overload methods. That is you can not have both

```
@property(nonatomic) SCNVector3 position;
@property(nonatomic) simd_float3 position API_AVAILABLE(macos(10.13), ios(11.0), tvos(11.0), watchos(4.0));
```

The new SIMD-based API needed a different name, and that's why SceneKit exposes `simdPosition`.

Comment: great answers, that make sense.