# What is simdTransform in SceneKit and ARKit?

Tags: swift, scenekit, augmented-reality, arkit, realitykit

In different ARKit and SceneKit projects, I see people working with **simdTransform**.

But I can't understand why they are using it?

And when should I use it?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/accelerate/simd

Comment: This question is too board to answer here.

Answer (score 4):

In the world of 3D graphics, `simdTransform` 4x4 matrices is a regular way to work with translation, rotation, scaling, shearing and projection of 3D models, cameras and lights.

Here's what Apple says about [simdTransform](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnnode/2881843-simdtransform) :

> **`simdTransform`** is the combination of the [node](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnnode)’s `simdRotation`, `simdPosition`, and `simdScale` properties. The default transform is the ***identity matrix***.

```
var simdTransform: simd_float4x4 { get set }

// all these properties are parts of a simdTransform
var simdPosition: simd_float3 { get set }
var simdRotation: simd_float4 { get set }
var simdEulerAngles: simd_float3 { get set }
var simdOrientation: simd_quatf { get set }
var simdScale: simd_float3 { get set }
var simdPivot: simd_float4x4 { get set }
```

Here's how 4x4 identity matrix looks like:

```
      x  y  z
   ┌              ┐
x  |  1  0  0  0  |
y  |  0  1  0  0  |
z  |  0  0  1  0  |
   |  0  0  0  1  |
   └              ┘
```

...and in code:

```
var transform = matrix_identity_float4x4
```

**EXAMPLE – Change a position using 4x4 matrix** :

```
      0  1  2  3      // column index
   ┌               ┐
   |  1  0  0  tx  |
   |  0  1  0  ty  |
   |  0  0  1  tz  |
   |  0  0  0  1   |
   └               ┘
```

...in code:

```
var translation = matrix_identity_float4x4

translation.columns.3.x = 10.25
translation.columns.3.y = 20.50
translation.columns.3.z = 30.75
```

> If you need more info on how 4x4 transformation matrix works, [look at this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45437037/what-does-the-different-columns-in-transform-in-arkit-represent/55695304#55695304).

P.S. **SIMD** stands for **Single Instruction**, **Multiple Data**. You can read about it [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44756858/what-does-the-simd-prefix-mean-in-scenekit).

[image]