# What's the difference between using ARAnchor to insert a node and directly insert a node?

Tags: swift, augmented-reality, arkit

In ARKit, I have found 2 ways of inserting a node after the hitTest

1. Insert an ARAnchor then create the node in [`renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer, nodeFor anchor: ARAnchor) -> SCNNode?`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/arscnviewdelegate/2865801-renderer)

   ```
    let anchor = ARAnchor(transform:hit.worldTransform)
    sceneView.session.add(anchor:anchor)
   ```
2. Insert the node directly

   ```
    node.position = SCNVector3(hit.worldTransform.columns.3.x, hit.worldTransform.columns.3.y, hit.worldTransform.columns.3.z)
    sceneView.scene.rootNode.addChildNode(node)
   ```

Both look to work for me, but why one way or the other?

Answer (score 63, accepted):

**Update:** As of iOS 11.3 (aka "ARKit 1.5"), there *is* a difference between adding an `ARAnchor` to the session (and then associating SceneKit content with it through `ARSCNViewDelegate` callbacks) and just placing content in SceneKit space.

When you add an anchor to the session, you're telling ARKit that a certain point in world space is relevant to your app. ARKit can then do some extra work to make sure that its world coordinate space lines up accurately with the real world, at least in the vicinity of that point.

So, if you're trying to make virtual content appear "attached" to some real-world point of interest, like putting an object on a table or wall, you should see less "drift" due to world-tracking inaccuracy if you give that object an anchor than if you just place it in SceneKit space. And if that object moves from one static position to another, you'll want to remove the original anchor and add one at the new position afterward.

Additionally, in iOS 11.3 you can [opt in](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/arsessionobserver/2941046-sessionshouldattemptrelocalizati) to "relocalization", a process that helps ARKit resume a session after it gets interrupted (by a phone call, switching apps, etc). The session still works while it's trying to figure out how to map where you were before to where you are now, which might result in the world-space positions of anchors changing once relocalization succeeds.

(On the other hand, if you're just making space invaders that float in the air, perfectly matching world space isn't as important, and thus you won't really see much difference between anchor-based and non-anchor-based positioning.)

See the bit around "Use anchors to improve tracking quality around virtual objects" in Apple's [Handling 3D Interaction and UI Controls in Augmented Reality](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/handling_3d_interaction_and_ui_controls_in_augmented_reality) article / sample code.

*The rest of this answer remains historically relevant to iOS 11.0-11.2.5 and explains some context, so I'll leave it below...*

---

Consider first the use of `ARAnchor` *without* SceneKit.

- If you're using `ARSKView`, you need a way to reference positions / orientations in 3D (real-world) space, because SpriteKit isn't 3D. You need `ARAnchor` to keep track of positions in 3D so that they can get mapped into 2D.
- If you're building your own engine with Metal (or GL, for some strange reason)... that's not a 3D scene description API — it's a GPU programming API — so it doesn't really have a notion of world space. You can use `ARAnchor` as a bridge between ARKit's notion of world space and whatever you build.

So in some cases you need `ARAnchor` because that's the only sensible way to refer to 3D positions. (And of course, if you're using plane detection, you need `ARPlaneAnchor` because ARKit will actually move those relative to scene space as it refined its estimates of where planes are.)

---

With `ARSCNView`, SceneKit already has a 3D world coordinate space, and ARKit does all the work of making that space match up to the real-world space ARKit maps out. So, given a `float4x4` transform that describes a position (and orientation, etc) in world space, you can either:

- Create an `ARAnchor`, add it to the session, and respond to `ARSCNViewDelegate` callback to provide SceneKit content for each anchor, which ARKit will add to and position in the scene for you.
- Create an `SCNNode`, set its `simdTransform`, and add it as a child of the scene's `rootNode`.

As long as you have a running `ARSession`, there's no difference between the two approaches — they're equivalent ways to say the same thing. So if you like doing things the SceneKit way, there's nothing wrong with that. (You can even use `SCNVector3` and `SCNMatrix4` instead of SIMD types if you want, but you'll have to convert back and forth if you're also getting SIMD types from ARKit APIs.)

---

The one time these approaches differ is when the session is reset. If world tracking fails, you resume an interrupted session, and/or
you start a session over again, "world space" may no longer line up with the real world in the same way it did when you placed content in the scene.

In this case, you can have ARKit remove anchors from the session — see the [`run(_:options:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/arsession/2875735-run) method and [`ARSession.RunOptions`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/arsession.runoptions). (Yes, all of them, because at this point you can't trust any of them to be valid anymore.) If you placed content in the scene using anchors and delegate callbacks, ARKit will nuke all the content. (You get delegate callbacks that it's being removed.) If you placed content with SceneKit API, it stays in the scene (but most likely in the wrong place).

So, which to use sort of depends on how you want to handle session failures and interruptions (and outside of that there's no real difference).

Comment: So the reasons: 1) ARNode is suitable for non-SceneKit engine (SpriteKit, Metal, etc), for SceneKit it is the same (since ARKit derived from SceneKit and has the same world coordinate), 2) if tracking fails, ARKit can automatically removed all ARAnchor (and thus the associated nodes) but SceneKit don't. Correct?

Comment: @LimThyeChean Yup.

Comment: @rickster thanks for the explanation! This saved me a lot of time.

Comment: I think I got more confused. So do we need to add the anchor and THEN the node via the delegate method. Or is it okay if we just add the Node and that's it? What is 'the right way', the proper way ? I feel the right way is to add the anchor then the node.

Comment: Add the anchor, then use the delegate callback to add content under the node ARKit creates for you.

Comment: Can SCNNode position to Latitude and longitude, So that I can track object on map?

Comment: NO @Rajesh that is a different question, unrelated to this topic. Visit ARCoreLocation third party library in google.

Comment: @rickster Regarding your update for iOS 11.3 - How does ARKit improve tracking for areas near the anchors in the scene?

Comment: @bartzy Magic secret sauce? The Apple documentation I linked in the answer is all they’ve said, so whatever the mechanism it’s all under the hood. You just place anchors and then you might notice an reduction in how much virtual objects appear to drift with camera movement.

Answer (score 2):

SCNVector3 is just "a representation of a three-component vector." [SCNVector3 docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnvector3).

When using ARAnchor, you have access to a three-component vector, but also you are able "to track the positions and orientations of real or virtual objects relative to the camera" [ARAnchor docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/aranchor). And that's why you use the session to add the anchor instead of using the scene.

See the docs and you can see the difference in terms of the API :)

Hope it helps.

Comment: That does not explain the difference between using a `SCNNode` with its `transform` property and an `ARAnchor` with its `transform`.

Comment: @orangenkopf You are right, both works. In fact, Apple seems to list these 2 ways are alternative to each other, but why do I want to add an extra ARAnchor for each node? The node seems to position well. Apple doc: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/arscnview/providing_3d_virtual_content_with_scenekit

Comment: An anchor has a set position in the real world. You can not move an anchor. Adding a node just adds some visuals and you can later change the node's position. It makes sense that the API is adding anchor for e.g. planes but I don't see a reason why you should add one manually